# iOS Custom View's methods not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller `CaptureDataVC` and a custom view `KeyboardView`.

`KeyboardView` has all the init functions required to work as needed:
`-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` and `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`

In `CaptureDataVC`'s xib file I have a `UIView` with custom class `KeyboardView`.

The view renders just fine. The problem is that I cannot call any of the methods in `KeyboardView` (It compiles and I don't get any errors but the methods aren't called).

So basically I can't do this:

**CaptureDataVC.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet KeyboardView  *keyboardView;
```

**CaptureDataVC.m**

```
[self.keyboardView foo];
```

**KeyboardView.m**

```
-(void) foo {
    NSLog(@"Hello World!"); //Won't print anyting
}
```

Any ideas ?

**Edit:**

[image]

The custom class is set to the blue view

Comment: Can you poste a screen shot of the xib file when your `KeyboardView` is selected and the Identity Inspector is open? Does the Class say `KeyboardView`?

Comment: @HAS as you can see it does ...

Comment: Do you have the IBOutlet attached in the storyboard,? Also it should be weak not retain.

Comment: @BooRanger yes they are attached. Kinda new to iOS, haven't figured all these things out yet. From what I just read on the internet, I can use weak instead of retain cuz the setter generated by synthesize will retain. Is that right ?

Comment: We use strong to say to "hey what ever happens while i"m alive your alive" and weak to say "Hey while your alive im going hold on to you but if you die well thats ok I'll let you go". So while the view is alive your keyboard view is alive.

Comment: Is the IBOutlet keyboardView `nil`?   Despite everything else mentioned here, it still could be.   And regarding the above comments, you should use weak (and not the implicit strong) because the view is retained by its superview.  Views are owned through the view hierarchy, not by their controllers.

Comment: I just checked and yes `keyboardView` is `nil`. Kind of strange, `initWithCoder` is called for that view... Any ideas why ?

Comment: As for the `IBOutlet` which should be weak instead of retain, it's because I am not using ARC ...

Comment: @kimimsc use `@` to notify people of comments.  The IBOutlet is likely not hooked up properly in IB.  Don't use `retain` if you're using ARC here.   Controller shouldn't retain the view if it has a parent view.

Comment: @stevesliva yeah had forgotten the @ on last comment. Just did the whole IB creation again but didn't change anything. As I said in my last comment I am not using ARC ...

Comment: Have you added any breakpoints to follow the flow of the code? Such is whether or not `keyboardView` is `nil` at any point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the first questions are:

1. Is the `[self.keyboardView foo];` line run? Put a breakpoint there.
2. If yes, is `self.keyboardView` not nil? When the debugger has stopped on the previous breakpoint, type `po self.keyboardView` in the debugger to check.

A classic mistake is to assume that `self.someView` is always set. Actually it won't, before view and outlets have been loaded. See the documentations of `viewDidLoad`, and `isViewLoaded`.

Comment: Was trying to call those methods from within `CaptureDataVC`'s init mehtod ... Just moved them to `viewDidLoad` and voilà ...

Comment: Should probably mark this answer as solved, looks like the solution is here

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help!

Answer (score 5):

Please check if KeyboardView`s outlet property setup: if property is nil, nothing will happen

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to initialize custom view manually as its added in view controller. All you have to do just check where you have been calling your custom view method. It should be called after your view loaded. i.e viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 1):

In `CaptureDataVC.m` you must allocate the memory to object as:

```
self.keyboardView=[[KeyboardView alloc]init];
```

and the call your method as:

```
[self.keyboardView foo];
```

it will work.

Comment: Thanks for answering but what I was doing wrong was that I was trying to access the view before it was loaded (in the init method). Just needed to move my code into viewDidLoad method

Comment: That is great to hear !! :) perfct

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve your desired result using the delegates.implement the delegates of keyboard view in your viewcontroller.